# Proof of a statement about the variance of an OLS estimator

Tags: variance, least-squares, r-squared

I am currently taking an econometrics course and in the lecture notes there is a statement about the variance of an OLS estimator that I am unable to prove. The statement is as follows:

Suppose the true model is given by $Y_i=α+βX_i+ϵ_i$ and the standard LRM assumptions hold. However, one runs a regression using the model $Y_i=α+βX_i+\gamma W_i +ϵ_i$, where $W_i$ is an irrelevant variable. Then $Var(\hat\beta_n|x,w)=\frac{1}{(1-R_1^2)}\frac{\sigma^2}{x^TM_ix}$, where $M_i$ is the residual maker matrix and $R_1^2$ is the $R^2$ in the regression of $X_i$ on $W_i$

If someone could explain how to prove this claim, I'd be very thankful!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It might help you to know that the $\frac{1}{1-R_i^2}$ is called the *variance inflation factor*. The name comes from the fact that, when features are related (in the sense that this $R_i^2$ is high), the coefficient variances and standard errors are increased above where they would be if, all else equal, there were no such relationship between the features. The variance of the coefficient, all else equal is the rest of that formula.

Comment: Thank for the intuitive explanation, but I'm looking for a mathematical way to derive the formula